# Updated Amazon SNS Push Certificate for iOS. Notifications stopped

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have an app that's been live with push notifications for close to a year now.  It's using Amazon's SNS service to provide the push notifications, but the certificate expired having followed Amazon's instructions, I created the new certificate through Apple's member center, installed it on my machine, exported it and its private key into a .p12 file, and finally uploaded that .p12 file to the Amazon SNS dashboard.

Everything seemed to work fine.  But now when I try to actually send a push to my test device... nothing happens.

I've tried installing mobileconfig file mentioned here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG24

...and in the console log I can see lots of messages like this

> Aug 20 11:49:51 *(my phone's name)* apsd[86] : 2014-08-20 11:49:51 -0500 apsd[86]:  setEnabledTopics:{(
>       )} ignoredTopics:{(
>       )} opportunisticTopics:{(
>           "*(my app id)*"
>       )} forCategory UsesALS pretend NO change NewlyEnabled

...which I assume means the app is telling apple to send it push notifications.  But still nothing.

I have a second app set up the same way and I'm able to send notifications to THAT app through the SNS dashboard, so I know I'm sending them properly, but I'm not sure what else to do to debug this.  What could be the problem here?

Comment: Update: I've tried switching back to my old Apple APS certificate (not quite expired) certificate, which hasn't been revoked yet.  That one actually works.  But the new one I generated does not...

Comment: Update: Three times I walked through the process of generating fresh public/private keys and a fresh certificate.  The third time through it finally worked right away and I was able to send a successful push notification.  No clue what the difference was that time around.